# QList assignment directly [cause crash] or append [okay]

Tags: c++, qt, append, variable-assignment, qlist

What is the difference between these two options?

Option 1:

```
QList <double> arr_tmp = arr_one;    //arr_one also  QList <double>
```

Option 2:

```
QList <double> arr_tmp;
arr_tmp.append(arr_one);
```

Every 20 ms, I need to call one of these, and each time "arr_tmp" gets about 20,000 items from arr_one.

When I use option 1, my App (Windows 10 + QT 6.5 + MSVC2019) crashes very often, however option 2 works fine.

Very appreciated if any words!!

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the rest of the application (eg what happens to `arr_one` before/after this line), but QList being implicitly shared may very well contribute to this problem.

Comment: Copying makes the data [shared](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), appending doesn't.